# What happens if I move folders into an IMAP account in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

A friend of mine is using Outlook (I think 2019) on his Windows PC. He asked me to add another mail account to his Outlook instance, which I did (as IMAP). He already has another account in the instance (POP/SMPT). Now he would like to have all his old emails in the folder of his new account.

I was planning to just move all the "old" folders (ca. 15 folders containing 15000+ mails) to the inbox of the new account via drag and drop. But I'm wondering what will happen in this case.

- will the old emails get synchronized into the new account via IMAP, meaning to the server?
- or will the drag-and-drop changes only apply to this outlook instance, but not change anything on the server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire purpose of IMAP is bidirectional sync. The folder tree you see in an IMAP client is meant to represent the server's storage – creating folders via IMAP will create them on the IMAP server; moving messages into an IMAP folder will upload them into the IMAP server. This is true even for Outlook.

In recent Outlook versions (I think 2016 and later?) this synchronization is no longer immediate – if you move a *large* folder to an IMAP account, first the changes are applied only to the local PST/OST, then synchronized with the server in background. (For 15k messages it may even take an hour or two.) In older versions, if I remember, the process was synchronous.

Comment: When using drag and drop, I think that it's better to move messages in small chunks to prevent problems. Email service providers might have quotas, especially for users in a free tier. Several years ago, I knew about users having problems. Still, I'm not sure if that was caused by IMAP or something related to the message size (having a lot of messages with large attachments and lengthy email bodies caused by email "replying all" in the message chain).

Answer (score 1):

If you move folders into an IMAP account in Outlook, you are essentially moving the emails from one server to another. This means that your local copies of the emails will be deleted and you will have to sync with the IMAP server to access them.

Depending on how many emails you have and how fast your internet connection is, this may take some time and bandwidth.

Also, some IMAP servers may have different folder structures or limitations than your original server, so you may encounter some errors or inconsistencies in the process.

You may want to backup your emails before you move them, or create a new folder in your IMAP account and copy the emails there instead of moving them. That way, you can keep both versions of your emails and compare them if needed.